# Android build release | Is there any specific way to allow the android app download for some selected mobile phones only?

Tags: android

I am creating an app for store management that will be used in retail stores for managing user and other store related activities like redeeming coupons / points. The requirement is to install this app on some specific devices only provided by stores. I am listing use case below for better understanding:
There are two Samsung M51 devices, let's say SM001 and SM002 so the app should only work on SM001 not on SM002.

There may be below ways(theoretical) to achieve this:

1. It will not install on restricted devices, but it does not seem feasible as we need a mechanism that puts a check on deviceID(Some device specific identifier) before installing it.
2. It can be installed on any device but when the user opens it then it will check with the list of allowed deviceIDs and then show an error.

from above two assumptions another question arises that what will be the unique identifier for a device and that never changes?

Comment: Can this link be a solution :https://ssaurel.medium.com/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb#:~:text=This%20unique%20ID%20can%20be,well%20as%20some%20satellite%20phones

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to restrict on which devices the app can be installed on, you can restrict _who_ is allowed to install the app (i.e. by setting up a [Closed or Internal test track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en) in Google Play).

Comment: Maybe you can use the device's unique ID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id